# MS Excel Conditional Format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I seek to create a conditional format on a spreadsheet which logs invoices on the date they were received. Below is the sample

[image: Sample Excel Data]

I want to create a conditional format where the 'date invoice received' cell turns orange when 9 days have passed. The other condition which MUST be satisfied for the cell to turn orange is for there NOT to be a "Y" value in the first column, meaning the invoice was paid.

So both the invoice should be received and showing a received date, and second it should not be Paid: blank value in column A. Thirdly 9 days should pass since the received date for the 'date invoice received' column cell to turn orange.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the range to be formatted. Assuming B2 was the cell you first clicked when making this selection, go to "Conditional formatting" -> "Use a formula..." and enter `=AND(B2<=TODAY()-9, A2<>"Y")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a column with the [Today function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-5eb3078d-a82c-4736-8930-2f51a028fdd9) date, then compare **TODAY** cell with **Invoice received date+9** cell and if TODAY is smaller then **Invoice received date** cell turn orange

You have to set another IF condition to check "Y" value in the first column

So you can set

> =and((B2+9)<=TODAY(),B1<>"Y")

In the picture below you can see where to find those istructions (sorry for my regional version)

[image: conditional formatting excel]